# Removing first item in an ordered list isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to remove the first item from an ordered list every time a button is clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<ol class="rem">
   <li>First item</li>
   <li>Second item</li>
   <li>Third item</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="eliminate()">Eliminate</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function eliminate(){
   $('ol.rem li:first-child').remove();
}
```

```js
function eliminate() {
  $('ol.rem li:first-child').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="rem">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="eliminate()">Eliminate</button>
```

I've been reading how other people do it but I can't seem to get mines to work. No matter what method I try, nothing seems to work. Is there something wrong I'm doing that I'm just not seeing?

I've also imported jQuery like this:

`<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Thank you!

Comment: There is no element that matches the `ol.rem` selector.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, sorry about that, it's suppose to be class="rem", I forgot to change it back after testing several methods. Even with class being correct, it doesn't work? :(

Comment: Your code does indeed work once you fix that, see snippet. Voting to close as typo

Comment: @CertainPerformance, okay, but I still have the problem that it is not working for me... I see that it works in your snippet, but it doesn't work in my file. Thank you

Comment: Please produce a [MCVE] that illustrates the problem you're having, then

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I hope this is a good example? https://imgur.com/a/etAMYdB

Comment: That would be a good example if you put the code in the post and not a photo; however, it did reveal your problem. Take a look at my detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not including jQuery in your code, this is per the screenshot you provided in your comments.

Check at the demo at the bottom to see how you can accomplish without using jQuery

[image]

#### Solution

Add this between the `<head>` tags of your document

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

#### Working Code (Copy/Paste and Try)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Blog</title>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function eliminate() {
                $('ol.rem li:first-child').remove();
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <h2>Hello</h2>
            <ol class="rem">
                <li>First Item</li>
                <li>Second Item</li>
                <li>Third Item</li>
                <li>Fourth Item</li>
                <li>Fifth Item</li>
            </ol>
            <button onclick="eliminate()">Eliminate</button>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### No jQuery Version

Depending on what you need jQuery for, you might not need to use it at all. This code accomplishes the same thing using Vanilla (regular) JavaScript.

```js
function eliminate() {
  document.querySelector('ol.rem li:first-child').remove();
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <ol class="rem">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
    <li>Fifth Item</li>
  </ol>
  <button onclick="eliminate()">Eliminate</button>
</section>
```